# how to convert a matrix in string in order to output it in JTextArea

Tags: java

I am a beginner in Java, and I need help. I am trying to print a matrix in a JTextArea. But I don't know how to convert the matrix into a string in order to print it in the JTextArea. I am trying to use `matrica.get(i)`, but I don't know how to use it for a matrix. Or is there any other possibility? Can anyone help me please?

Here I fill the matrix:

```
public  void fillMatricen(){
    for (int i =0; i<x; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<y; j++){
            matrica[i][j]=(int) ((double) Math.random()*10);
        }
    }
}
```

And here I am trying to print it:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        String row1 = inrows.getText();
        int row2 = Integer.parseInt(row1);
        String col1 = incolumns.getText();
        int col2 = Integer.parseInt(col1);
        fillMatricen(); 
        for( int i=0; i<row2; i++){
            for( int j=0; j<col2; j++){
                matricaString= matricaString + matrica.get(i);
            }
        }
        matric.setText(matricaString);

    }
```

Comment: user3233650. You've edited your question to hide it's contents. First, this does not accomplish the intended results (there is a editing log, we can still see the original question). Second, by doing that you are stealing for the community (since other users will not be able to benefit from it).

Comment: @Jongware already restored the last version of the question. Do not try to hide if any further.

Comment: "You've edited your question to hide it's contents." - to play devil's advocate, he got a rather rude reception as a beginning programmer. The question was (1) closed as too broad, (2) closed as too off-topic, and (3) he was downvoted. I don't think the question was too broad or off topic. In fact, I think the folks who closed were a bit lazy and did not find a proper close reason for a post they considered beneath them from a beginner. If he feels the community is not interested in his question, he probably tried to remove it since the community appear to want it gone.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This worked very well:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.*;

public class ConvertMatrix extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    JLabel rows = new JLabel ("Numri i rreshtave"+'\n'); 
    JTextField inrows = new JTextField (5);
    JLabel columns = new JLabel ("Numri i kolonave eshte");
    JTextField incolumns = new JTextField (5);
    JLabel matrix = new JLabel("Matrica ka formen");
    JTextField inmatrix = new JTextField(30);
    JButton mat = new JButton("Afisho matricen");
    JTextArea matric = new JTextArea(10,21);

    int x;
    int y; 
    double[][] matrica;

    public ConvertMatrix (){ 
        super ("Matrica e konvertuar");
        setSize(300, 250);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        Container content = getContentPane();
        content.setLayout(new FlowLayout ());
        content.setBackground(Color.pink);
        content.add(rows);
        rows.setForeground(Color.blue);
        content.add(inrows);
        content.add(columns);
        columns.setForeground(Color.red);
        content.add(incolumns);
        content.add(matrix);
        content.add(inmatrix);
        matrix.setForeground(Color.gray );
        content.add(mat);

        content.add(matric);

        mat.addActionListener(this);   

        setContentPane(content);
    }

    public  void mbushMatricen(int x, int y){
       matrica = new double[x][y];
       for (int i =0; i<x; i++){
       for (int j=0; j<y; j++){
           matrica[i][j]=((double) Math.random()*10);       
       }
    }
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
    String rresht = inrows.getText();
    int rreshtii = Integer.parseInt(rresht);//kthimi i stringut ne integer
    String shtyll = incolumns.getText();
    int shtylle = Integer.parseInt(shtyll);
    mbushMatricen(rreshtii,shtylle);
    String matricaString = "";
        for(int i=0; i<rreshtii; i++){
            for( int j=0; j<shtylle; j++){
                matricaString += matrica[i][j] + "  ";
            }
        matricaString += "\n";
        }
    matric.setText(matricaString);
}

    public static void main(String []args){
        ConvertMatrix m = new ConvertMatrix();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should replace ìnt[][] matrica;` to `double[][] matrica;` instancitate matrica in `mbushMatricen`. `matrica = new double[x][y];`
Mark Q as accept if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line

```
matricaString = matricaString + matrica.get(i);
```

with

```
matricaString += matrica[i][j];
```

As it appears in `fillMatricen`, `matrica` is an array of array. So you can't use any `get` method for accessing an element from `matrica`.

Comment: IT SAID THAT GET CAN NOT BE RESOLVED AS A FIELD

Comment: @user3233650 Relax dude ... it was a small mistyping :p

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your data type is, but Java collection generally have a toString() method that will print themselves. I personally don't like to display that output because it has a bunch of brackets that aren't attractive to humans.

A simple way is to loop through your data using String.format(formatString, obj); and add those pieces into a StringBuffer (using StringBuffer.append()). Then do a toString on the StringBuffer to put it in the JTextArea. You can even add html tags into the text so your data shows up in tabular form.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
    String row1 = inrows.getText();
    int row2 = Integer.parseInt(row1);
    String col1 = incolumns.getText();
    int col2 = Integer.parseInt(col1);
    fillMatricen(row2, col2);
    String matricaString = '';
    for( int i=0; i<row2; i++){
        for( int j=0; j<col2; j++){
            matricaString += matrica[i][j] + "  ";
        }
        matricaString += "\n"
    }
    matric.setText(matricaString);

}

public  void fillMatricen(int x, int y){
    for (int i =0; i<x; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<y; j++){
            matrica[i][j]=(int) ((double) Math.random()*10);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share us the whole class.

Comment: it gives me an error : Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at ConvertMatrix.mbushMatricen(ConvertMatrix.java:87)
 at ConvertMatrix.actionPerformed(ConvertMatrix.java:98)   line 87 is   matrica[i][j]=(int) ((double) Math.random()*10); and line 98 is: fillMatricen(row2,col2);

Comment: Replace `matrica[i][j]=(int) ((double) Math.random()*10);` with `matrica[i][j]=(double) ((double) Math.random()*10);`

Comment: so i shared the whole class...can you help me now?

Comment: please what can I do now?