# Output a matrix in JTextArea

Tags: java

I am trying to output a matrix in JTextArea, but I have problems with converting the matrix into string in order to output it...
My whole class is:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import java.awt.*;

 class ConvertMatrix extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

     JLabel rows = new JLabel ("Numri i rreshtave"+'\n'); 
     JTextField inrows = new JTextField (5);
     JLabel columns = new JLabel ("Numri i kolonave eshte");
     JTextField incolumns = new JTextField (5);
     JLabel matrix = new JLabel("Matrica ka formen");
     JTextField inmatrix = new JTextField(30);
     JButton mat = new JButton("Afisho matricen");
     JTextArea matric = new JTextArea(10,21);




     int x;
     int y; 
   int[][] matrica = new int [x][y];




    public ConvertMatrix ()
    { 
        super ("Matrica e konvertuar");
        setSize(300, 250);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        Container content = getContentPane();
        content.setLayout(new FlowLayout ());
        content.setBackground(Color.pink);
        content.add(rows);
        rows.setForeground(Color.blue);
        content.add(inrows);
        content.add(columns);
        columns.setForeground(Color.red);
        content.add(incolumns);
        content.add(matrix);
        content.add(inmatrix);
        matrix.setForeground(Color.gray );
        content.add(mat);

        content.add(matric);


        mat.addActionListener(this);   


        setContentPane(content);

    }
public  void mbushMatricen(int x, int y){

    for (int i =0; i<x; i++)

    for (int j=0; j<y; j++)

     matrica[i][j]=(int) ((double) Math.random()*10);       

        }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
    {

        String rresht = inrows.getText();
        int rreshtii = Integer.parseInt(rresht);//kthimi i stringut ne integer
        String shtyll = incolumns.getText();
        int shtylle = Integer.parseInt(shtyll);
        mbushMatricen(rreshtii,shtylle);
         String matricaString = "";
            for( int i=0; i<rreshtii; i++){
                for( int j=0; j<shtylle; j++){
                    matricaString += matrica[i][j] + "  ";
                }
                matricaString += "\n";
            }
            matric.setText(matricaString);      


    }



         public static void main(String []args)
         { ConvertMatrix m = new ConvertMatrix();



}




       }


 the problem is that it gives me these error:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at ConvertMatrix.mbushMatricen(ConvertMatrix.java:87)
    at ConvertMatrix.actionPerformed(ConvertMatrix.java:98)
```

where line 87 is: `matrica[i][j]=(int) ((double) Math.random()*10);`
where line 98 is: `mbushMatricen(rreshtii,shtylle);`

I have also tried these method:

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
        {

```
        String rresht = inrows.getText();
        int rreshtii = Integer.parseInt(rresht);//kthimi i stringut ne integer
        String shtyll = incolumns.getText();
        int shtylle = Integer.parseInt(shtyll);
        mbushMatricen(rreshtii,shtylle);
           StringBuilder matricaString = new StringBuilder();

            for( int i=0; i<rreshtii; i++)
                for( int j=0; j<shtylle; j++)


                matricaString.append(Character.toString(matrica[i][j]));


 matric.setText(matricaString.toString());

    }
```

but is said to me: `The method toString(char) in the type Character is not applicable for the arguments (int)`

PLEASE CAN YOU HELP ME...I am a beginner in java

Comment: but can you help me? can you say me what can I do....in both cases i have problems...please

Comment: See this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343026/how-to-convert-a-matrix-in-string-in-order-to-output-it-in-jtextarea/21343557?noredirect=1#comment32179499_21343557]

Comment: Have you considered using a `JTable` instead?

Comment: *"The method toString(char) in the type Character is not applicable for the arguments (int)"* would suggest you need to use `Integer.toString` instead

Comment: MadProgrammer beat me to it ... `Character.toString(ch)` takes a character and always returns a `String` whose length is 1, and whose one character is the character you give it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked well:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.*;

public class ConvertMatrix extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    JLabel rows = new JLabel ("Numri i rreshtave"+'\n'); 
    JTextField inrows = new JTextField (5);
    JLabel columns = new JLabel ("Numri i kolonave eshte");
    JTextField incolumns = new JTextField (5);
    JLabel matrix = new JLabel("Matrica ka formen");
    JTextField inmatrix = new JTextField(30);
    JButton mat = new JButton("Afisho matricen");
    JTextArea matric = new JTextArea(10,21);

    int x;
    int y; 
    double[][] matrica;

    public ConvertMatrix (){ 
        super ("Matrica e konvertuar");
        setSize(300, 250);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        Container content = getContentPane();
        content.setLayout(new FlowLayout ());
        content.setBackground(Color.pink);
        content.add(rows);
        rows.setForeground(Color.blue);
        content.add(inrows);
        content.add(columns);
        columns.setForeground(Color.red);
        content.add(incolumns);
        content.add(matrix);
        content.add(inmatrix);
        matrix.setForeground(Color.gray );
        content.add(mat);

        content.add(matric);

        mat.addActionListener(this);   

        setContentPane(content);
    }

    public  void mbushMatricen(int x, int y){
       matrica = new double[x][y];
       for (int i =0; i<x; i++){
       for (int j=0; j<y; j++){
           matrica[i][j]=((double) Math.random()*10);       
       }
    }
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
    String rresht = inrows.getText();
    int rreshtii = Integer.parseInt(rresht);//kthimi i stringut ne integer
    String shtyll = incolumns.getText();
    int shtylle = Integer.parseInt(shtyll);
    mbushMatricen(rreshtii,shtylle);
    String matricaString = "";
        for(int i=0; i<rreshtii; i++){
            for( int j=0; j<shtylle; j++){
                matricaString += matrica[i][j] + "  ";
            }
        matricaString += "\n";
        }
    matric.setText(matricaString);
}

    public static void main(String []args){
        ConvertMatrix m = new ConvertMatrix();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...you help me so much...but is there any way to have the numbers in matrix integer...because I dont want them double

Answer (score 0):

You should use DecimalFormat class

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0");

matricaString += formatter.format(matrica[i][j]) + "  ";
```

[DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Format.html)